# How to Post Multiple Data From View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to post multiple data objects to my controller. I will share my css code and screenshot of the page to explain the problem more precisely.

CSS code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Per Diem Type
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody >
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@item.Date" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                    <input asp-for="@item.Amount" class="form-control" id="amount-@item.Id" disabled>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
                    <select name="cars" id="pardiem-type-@item.Id" onclick="fillAmountValue('amount-@item.Id','pardiem-type-@item.Id')">
                        <option value="Transportation">Transportation</option>
                        <option value="Accomodation">Accomodation</option>
                        <option value="VPN Fee">VPN Fee</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                
            </tr>
        }      
    </tbody>
    
</table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

[image]

As you can see in the above image there are empty fields waiting for to be filled. They are currently empty in the database. What I want is when user fills the empty fields, user can choose them arbitrary, and presses the save button program should post and apply the changes in the database.

I will also share my model down the below. Only Date, Amount and Type should be entered by the user side.

```
public class SubPeriods
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public EmployeeIdentity EmployeeIdentity { get; set; }
    public int? Amount { get; set; }
    public string? Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How is your controller snippet can you include that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long effort and a little bit search I found my own way. Here is what i did.

First of all you should change your model to IList in m `@model IList<SubPeriods>`
.Second thing was turning foreachloop into for loop. If you look at my question you should see a foreach loop. Here is my new view.

```
<form method="post" asp-action="EditPOST">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Amount
                </th>
                <th>
                    Per Diem Type
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <input asp-for="@Model[i].Id" hidden />
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].Date" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].Amount" class="form-control" id="amount-@Model[i].Id" readonly >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-select" asp-for="@Model[i].Type" id="pardiem-type-@Model[i].Id" onclick="fillAmountValue('amount-@Model[i].Id','pardiem-type-@Model[i].Id')">
                            <option value="@Model[i].Type" selected>@Model[i].Type</option>
                            <option value="Transportation" >Transportation</option>
                            <option value="Accomodation" >Accomodation</option>
                            <option value="VPN Fee">VPN Fee</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Instead of `@item.Date` you should trasform it to `@Model[i].Date` and you are good to submit.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript in the view to submit the data, use List or array in the controller to receive the data.

```
const submitButton = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // Prevent the default form submission behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get all rows in the table
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

  // Create an array to hold the data from each row
  const data = [];

  // Loop through each row and add its data to the array
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const dateInput = row.querySelector('input[name="Date"]');
    const amountInput = row.querySelector('input[name="Amount"]');
    const typeSelect = row.querySelector('select[name="Type"]');

    data.push({
      Date: dateInput.value,
      Amount: amountInput.value,
      Type: typeSelect.value
    });
  });

  // Make a POST request to the server using fetch
  fetch('/url/to/post/data', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      // Handle successful response
    } else {
      // Handle error response
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle network or other errors
  });
});
```